Connecting to two different wireless networks on different bands using the same network device on Linux
Nowadays, our wireless network adapters are able to connect to both 5GHz and 2.4GHz wireless networks. I also noticed that in some operating systems and devices, it is possible to connect to two different networks at the same time using the same adapter, as long as each of these networks use a different frequency
You will notice this capability most often with:

Devices such as Android, Windows, etc. connecting to a WiFi network and opening a hotspot at the same time.
An Android or Windows device connecting to a wireless display (which utilizes WiFi Direct) and also staying connected to WiFi
(I am unfamiliar with Apple products so I can't comment on those)

This shows that in theory it can be done. In practice it's usually don't because that's usually not the intention of the user, but there are many instances where it can be useful
My question is, can this be done with Linux and NetworkManager? How can it be done?

It depends on the hardware and driver. I can do that on my laptop with Intel AX210, although last time I did it the driver was buggy for that and led to some serious system crash.

As @TomYan states, it depends very much on the network card. For example, I've found sometimes third-party drivers must be manually installed for Realtek chips, and the drivers may not be able to make full use of the devices capability. One driver I've used could only connect on the 2.4 GHz band.

@DrMoishePippik if I know for sure that the card is capable of it, because I was able to get it to work in Windows (e.g. by using wireless display casting, or opening a hotspot), is there a standard method of doing this on Linux?

@9a3eedi, there was no mention of the card capability, but of the availability Linux drivers.

Your first sentence made me misinterpret, I understood now.
